# jQuery: string convert to variable

Tags: javascript

I want string convert to variable:

```
var abc='b';
var b=5;
console.log(window[abc]);
```

in js, above is normal. when use jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var abc='b';
    var b=5;
    console.log(window[abc]);
});
```

show is undefined, so, how can I write? In second example, gain 5 through global object.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about scopes.

```
var b = 5;
```

Exists only in scope of your function(){ ... }, but you are trying to look for it in scope of window.

try this instead:

```
console.log(eval(abc))
```

or, assign b as a key to some temp object:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var scope = {};
   scope.abc = 'b';
   scope.b = 5;
   console.log(scope[scope.abc])
});
```

**UPDATE**

In case you want to use local scope, just replace "scope" with "this":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   this.abc = 'b';
   this.b = 5;
   console.log(this[this.abc])
});
```

Comment: in ready function, what can represent the scope? temp object is necessary? is there other method?

Comment: "this" is a scope for every function. You can use it, just replace "scope" with "this" in my answer

Comment: But you have to be aware, that every function can be applied to some existing scope, and $.ready does apply your function to something existing. So if you want to keep your vars away from trashing other scopes, temp var is best

Comment: thanks for your remind, 
$(document).ready(function(){
var abc='b';
var b=5;
console.log(this[abc]);
});
result is undefined still?

Answer (score 0):

`var abc` is defined within a function. So it's a 'local' variable, which isn't in the `window` object. Just use `console.log(abc)` and it'll be fine. In your first example `console.log(abc)` will work as well.

Comment: You better check what the output of `console.log(window[abc])` in the first example is ;)

Comment: In second, want gain 5 through global object~

Answer (score 0):

For quick example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var abc = 'b';
    this.b  = 5;

    console.log(this[abc]);
});
```